# Highchart: Tickmark placement for datetime axis

Tags: highcharts

We have a chart with two datetime series to display stock development over past years.
First series is a line chart with a data item for each month.
Second series is a column chart with a data item for every year.

I've put together an example: http://jsfiddle.net/kaiw/8E9nJ.

```
...
xAxis: [{
        type: "datetime"
    }]
...
```

We would now like to place the lables on the x-Axis between the ticks, like you can do for a category axis.
We have to work with datetime values and can't use categories because of the different number of data items per series.

Is there any other way how we can place the label between ticks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to documentantion tickmark is avaiable only for categorized axis. You can use x parameter for labels and set hardcoded value like in the example: http://jsfiddle.net/8E9nJ/3/

```
xAxis: [{
        id: "xAxis",
        type: "datetime",
        title: null,
        labels:{
            x:40
        }
    }],
```

Comment: Hardcoded values work as long as the user doesn't zoom in... . But I guess it's the best option as long as "between" is available for a categorized series only. Are there any attempts on Highchart side to make the feature available for datetime series too?

Comment: You can post your suggestion here highcharts.uservoice.com